# Dragula: Getting information from dragged item in

Tags: javascript, dragula

I am still learning JS and got into Dragula

Is there an easy way to send a console.log of the dragged item and the destination in vanilla JS? (I am not using React or Angular).

I figured I can do this like this:

```
<script>
dragula([
document.getElementById("to-do"),
document.getElementById("inprogress"),
document.getElementById("done")
]);
    
on("drop", function (el) {
   console.log("el");
}).
</script>
```

But clearly that doesn't work;

Any suggestions very welcome!

Comment: The `on` method likely needs to be used on the `dragula` output. Assign `dragula()` to a variable and then use that with `on`? Read more [on their github](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#usage).

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox, this is where I get lost already =( - any hints of how to do that?

Comment: Try `let drake = dragula` then use `drake.on`?

Comment: how/where could this be triggered?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: sorry, I guess I don't follow your suggestion. where would I add a console.log? do I need to create a new function? and if so, how would that be triggered?

Comment: Follow their instructions on creating event listeners? https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#usage https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/ they have plenty of examples

Comment: thanks @evolutionxbox not sure what went wrong, but rewrote the code and it works now, thx!